box office problem generalization
When doing combinatorics, I found the box office problem very interesting:
Assume that the box office has no changes initially, with $n$ customers having 5-dollar bills and $n$ customers having 10-dollar bills (each ticket costs 5 dollars) waiting in line. How many ways are there so that no customer has to wait for change?
The question itself is related to the Catalan number, so it is pretty easy to solve. However, I am curious about the generalization of this type of question:
Assume that the box office has no changes initially, and each ticket costs $k$ dollars. $n$ customers with $k$ dollar bills and $m$ customers with $tk$ dollar bills ($tn \ge m$) are waiting in line. How many ways are there so that no customer has to wait for change?
I tried to use graph theory to solve this problem. Starting at $(0,0)$, a customer with a $k$ dollar bill will move the point (creating a path) to $(x+k,y+1)$ and a customer with a $tk$ dollar bill will move it to $(x-tk,y+1)$. The only requirement here is that no path should be under the line $y=0$. However, I cannot see a solution when $t>2$. Are there any methods to solve the generalization more effectively?
Thank you in advance!

The value $k$ seems irrelevant here, so we shall ignore it. What you are asking is actually the number of $m$-Raney sequence, and the answer to it is the Fuss–Catalan number. (Sadly the Wikipedia page doesn’t seem rich enough.) I will refer to the formula (7.67) in Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik.

This is answered exactly by this generalization of Bertrand's ballot theorem.

Theorem: Let $a,b,r$ be positive integers with $a\ge rb$. In an election, candidate $A$ receives $a$ votes and candidate $B$ receives $b$ votes, and the votes are counted in a random order.

Strong version: The probability that, at every point in the counting process, that the number of votes for $A$ is strictly more than $r$ times the number of votes for $b$, is $(a-rb)/(a+b)$.
Weak version: The probability that, at every point in the counting process, that the number of votes for $A$ is at least $r$ times the number of votes for $b$, is $(a+1-rb)/(a+1)$.


Proof: See the source cited below. $\blacksquare$
The weak version applies to your problem. Think of a customer with a $\$k$ bill as a vote for $A$, and a customer with a $\$tk$ bill is a vote for $B$. At any point in the ticket-selling process, the number of customers with $\$k$ bills must be at least $(t-1)$ times the number of customers with $\$tk$ bills, so you apply the weak version with $a\gets n$, $b\gets m$, and $r\gets t-1$. The probability of success is $(n+1-(t-1)m)/(n+1)$, so the number of successful sequences is
$$
\frac{n+1-(t-1)m}{n+1}\binom{n+m}{n}.
$$

Renault, Marc. “Four Proofs of the Ballot Theorem.” Mathematics Magazine, vol. 80, no. 5, 2007, pp. 345–52. JSTOR, http://www.jstor.org/stable/27643060.

